UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use `zero_division` Error
I'm using Python on VS Code to start training with a Wine Quality ML.
But i keep getting
"UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples. Use zero_division parameter to control this behavior."
and my [accuracy][recall, fi-score] keep appearing blank:
   precision    recall  f1-score   support

           3       0.00      0.00      0.00         4
           4       1.00      0.06      0.11        17
           5       0.69      0.69      0.69       231
           6       0.57      0.62      0.60       226
           7       0.38      0.42      0.40        50
           8       0.00      0.00      0.00         5

    accuracy                           0.60       533
   macro avg       0.44      0.30      0.30       533
weighted avg       0.61      0.60      0.59       533

I've already set:
mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = mlp.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, predictions, zero_division=0))
print(predictions, '\n')

and everything else on my code seems to be working:
df = pd.read_csv('winequality-red.csv', sep =';')


X = df.drop('quality', axis = 1)
y = df['quality']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.333, random_state= 0)
X_train, X_test

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)

X_train = scaler.transform(X_train) 
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)

print(df.head())
print(df.describe().transpose())

print(X_train, '\n')
print(X_test, '\n')

mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(11, 11), activation='logistic', alpha=1e-06, batch_size='auto', beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, early_stopping=False, epsilon=1e-08, learning_rate='adaptive',
                    learning_rate_init=0.5, max_iter=10000, momentum=0.4, n_iter_no_change=10, nesterovs_momentum=True, power_t=0.5, random_state=1, shuffle=True, solver='sgd', tol=1e-09, validation_fraction=0.1,
                    verbose=10, warm_start=False)

mlp.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = mlp.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(y_test, predictions, zero_division=0))
print(predictions, '\n')

print(confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions), '\n')
print(classification_report(y_test, predictions))


e = y_test - predictions
e

